# MySQL query to calculate percentage of total column

Tags: mysql, sql

How to convert this result:

```
Group     |  Sum
Services  | 11120.99
Vendas    | 3738.00
```

Into:

```
Group     |  Sum
Services  | 74.84
Vendas    | 25.16
```

That is, the second displays the results as percentages of total.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT categories.cat AS 'Group', SUM(atual) AS 'Sum'
FROM `table1` INNER JOIN
     categories
     ON table1.category_id=categories.id
GROUP BY categoria
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can left join a total sum that is not grouped or split up, and divide that by your sum query. this way you are just doing the total select once for faster runtime

```
SELECT cat, sum_atual, sum_atual/total_atual as percent_atual 
FROM
(   SELECT categories.cat AS cat, SUM(atual) AS sum_atual
    FROM `table1` 
    JOIN categories ON table1.category_id=categories.id
    GROUP BY categoria
) t
LEFT JOIN 
(   SELECT SUM(atual) as total_atual
    FROM `table1`
) t1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this gives me the error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 8

Comment: well if you look at my query I do not use a LIMIT so that is a different part of the query where you have one... if you wouldn't mind sharing that part I can help you with the error

Comment: I'm just using the same query, no LIMIT.

Comment: Ok so i just reformatted it an made a few very slight changes so its easier to read. first. try to run this and let me know if it works. second. can you try to run the two queries separately and make sure they work properly?

Comment: ok did you run the queries separate? (i.e the query in the FROM() and the query in the LEFT JOIN() )???

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT categories.cat AS categoria, 
       SUM(atual) * 100 / (select sum(atual) from table1) AS percentages 
FROM `table1` 
INNER JOIN categories ON table1.category_id=categories.id 
GROUP BY categoria
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this doesn't add up to 100.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this several ways.  One is to just use a subquery in the `select` clause.  As written below, this assumes that the `category_id` column in `table1` always matches `categories`:

```
SELECT c.categoria AS "Group", SUM(t1.atual) AS "Sum",
       SUM(t1.atual) / (SELECT SUM(t1.atual) FROM table1) as "Percent"
FROM `table1` t1 INNER JOIN
     categories c
     ON t1.category_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.categoria;
```

I changed the `group by` clause as well.  It is a good idea for the `group by` and `select` to use the same columns.  And I added table aliases to all the column references, another good practice.