# PHP/MySQL update field proportionally

Tags: php, mysql

I have a betting script, which allows people to 'invest' in it. The table that stores how much and which user has invested, looks like this and is named 'invested':

[image: Invest table]

Every time someone places a bet and loses for example, it should share out those losses proportionally according to how much someone has invested and likewise if they win.

To clarify, since the sum of 'invested' is 0.6 if someone bets 0.6 and wins, both users in the example would lose their investment.

Lets say the bet amount is defined in `$wager`.

`$win_lose` when "1" means a win and when "0" means a loss.

Any ideas on the PHP script for this?

Comment: You would want to give each investor a percentage against the pot, then whatever the better wins would be deducted from the invested against the percentage.  So what is the level of precision, and how are you intending on handling rounding?

Comment: @Lance sorry I forgot to mention ($wager*$multiplier)-$wager would be the variable you would deduct from invested if the player won the bet. It should be to 8 decimal places. I thought about creating a new column called 'percentage' which is calculated every-time someone bets/invests/devests and using that as a way of calculating the proportion of the bet, but I worried that it could be exploited, if for example there were a lot of people betting at the same time.

Comment: cardinal rule of normalization: never stored derived data.  So just calculate the percentage "when the dealing is done".  It seems like you know what you want to do, so why the question?  Are you just asking for an example of the working code or just an example that guides you to figuring out the final code?

Comment: No distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)): thanks or greetings are never part of a  good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am CERTAIN that there is a more optimized query and procedure for this, but here is off the cuff code:

//! loop through your rows relative to your game

Use the sql from this answer to get your percentages: [MySQL query to calculate percentage of total column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769325/mysql-query-to-calculate-percentage-of-total-column)

//! then depending on the win/lose case debit/credit the records:

```
$multiplier = ($gameresult) ? -1 * $wager : $wager;

foreach($investors as $playerid => $stake)
{
    $val = $multiplier * $stake;
    $sql = "UPDATE invested SET invested = ROUND(invested+".$val.") WHERE player_id=".$playerid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, think this is enough info to try and figure out how to implement something.

Comment: No problem, lots of questions still exist that you'd need to provide you gameplay strategy to fully develop the code for you.  For example, what is the maximum debit, can the investor be in the negative, etc... best of luck!